# A two-way anova without repeated measures

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

I have a dataset with 2 independent variables (nominal variables) and one dependent variable.

My independent variables have 3 and 2 levels. For each combination of my independent variables, a different group of (balanced) participants were measured on the dependent variable.

As far as I understand, this means it is not a repeated-measures design. Can I still run a two-way ANOVA on this data? If not, what should I run instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like exactly the kind of data two-way ANOVA was invented to analyze. More details about the data would help. Why are you wondering? Why does the lack of repeated measures bother you?

Comment: Primarily because I usually see a two-way anova being called a two-way repeated measures anova. Are a 2way anova and a 2way rm anova different things, then?

Comment: @MitchellvanZuylen Yes. Two-way ANOVA can have no repeated measures, repeated measurements in one of the two factors, or repeated measurements in both factors.